# Can my existing Roth IRA be used as a spousal Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution

My wife and I both established separate Roth IRAs long ago and contributed over the years until we eventually hit the income limits.

Now that I'm retired and my wife is still working, we are again within the income limits and so we plan on resuming contributions to her Roth IRA.

In researching this, I learned about the Spousal Roth IRA, so I'd like to resume contributions to my Roth IRA as well.

My question is, can these spousal contributions go into my existing Roth IRA? That is, guessing that I need not create a separate new Roth IRA just for these spousal contributions? In researching this, I couldn't find any information that spoke to this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spousal IRA Roth is just the term for the logic that allows you to contribute - you use spousal's income. The Roth IRA is not in any way different, and you can make a new one or use the same for your contributions, as you like.

Basically, *you* are contributing to *your* Roth IRA. The money is from income from your spouse, but that doesn't matter to the contribution.

Answer (score -1):

No. IRAs are individual. The sum of contributions to your Traditional and Roth IRAs for a given year is at most $6,000 ($7,000 if you are 50 or older), and the sum of contributions to your wife's Traditional and Roth IRAs for a given year is also at most $6,000 ($7,000 if she is 50 or older). You cannot contribute $12,000 to your IRAs for a given year just because your wife is not contributing to hers.

The provision that "spousal" IRA refers to is that if you file jointly, you don't both need to have earned income in order to contribute. Otherwise, the amount you can contribute for a given year is capped by the amount of your earned income in that year, so if you no longer have earned income, you can no longer contribute. However, if you file jointly, your earned income is pooled, so that each spouse can contribute $6,000 to their own IRA even if one spouse does not work and the other earned $12,000. But you would still need to each contribute to your own IRAs, under the $6,000 (or $7,000) limit.

Comment: But do you have an answer to my specific question....?  ;)

Comment: I think you (@user102008) misunderstood the question. The idea is that OP contributes to his own IRA, but uses the spouse's money for it.

Comment: @Aganju: I guess it wasn't clear to me whether this "separate Roth IRA" is referring to his IRA or his wife's IRA. I thought if he was asking if there needs to be two separate IRAs between him and his spouse.